# How can I filter using uuid of Foreign Key in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have three tables

Token, Auth, UserProfile

```
class Token(models.Model):

    token = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255, default=uuid.uuid4().__str__())
    auth = models.ForeignKey(Auth, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

class Auth(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key = True, default = uuid.uuid4, editable = False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    user_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key = True, default = uuid.uuid4, editable = False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    auth = models.ForeignKey(Auth, models.DO_NOTHING)
```

How can I get UserProfile as I have Token class's object

I tried

```
user = UserProfile.objects.get(auth=token.auth)
```

which gives me the error

```
UserProfile matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: It means that there is no `UserProfile` with an `auth` for the given token. So that means that the token is "new", and there is no counterpart in the database.

Comment: but actually there is the token and everything else is right but when I get(auth=token.auth) it won't work. I think it is because of UUID as everything else is prefectly working

Comment: What if you `print(token.auth)`, can you see such record in the `auth` table in the database?

Comment: It gives me Auth object

Comment: with the same primary key as one the `UserProfile` links to?

Comment: yes same primary key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234130/discussion-between-mohit-kumar-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 0):

```
token = Token.objects.get(token = "anything")
user = UserProfile.objects.get(auth=token.auth)
print(user.username)
```

This works . No issues are there. May be you wouldn't populate your tables .

---

please add this print() function and check your terminal.

Comment: I did this but still giving same error. I am using mysql and my uuid is 32 bit maybe this is causing problem  , as currently I changed UUIDField to CharField